# How to make access or id token life extend for 10 years as written in the documentation?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito

I am using Amazon Cognito for authentication and I want to ask that my access token and id token get expired like in one hour, moreover I have gone through many answers they have told to use refresh token as they have a validity of 10 years,
so my question is how to use refresh token in android?

Right now after login, I am setting `CognitoCachingCredentialProvider`'s login map to the token - and I am using both Facebook and email login.

```
val authenticationHandler = object : AuthenticationHandler {
            override fun onSuccess(userSession: CognitoUserSession?, newDevice: CognitoDevice?) {

            //After Authentication User  Cognito Access Id and Access Secret Extraction
            currentSession = userSession!!

            //Getting Session Token
            val id = currentSession.idToken.jwtToken
            //Credential Provider
            val cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(this@LoginActivity,resources.getString(R.string.cognito_identity_pool_id),Regions.myRegion)
            cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.clear()
            //Login Map

            val login = HashMap<String,String>()
            login["myString"] = id
            cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.logins = login
            //Off the main thread
            SimpleAsyncTask(this@LoginActivity,cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider).execute()
        }

        override fun authenticationChallenge(continuation: ChallengeContinuation?) {
            continuation?.continueTask()
        }

        override fun getAuthenticationDetails(authenticationContinuation: AuthenticationContinuation, userId: String) {
            // The API needs user sign-in credentials to continue
            Log.d(TAG, "userId is : $userId")
            val authenticationDetails = AuthenticationDetails(userId, password, null)
            authenticationDetails.authenticationType = "USER_PASSWORD"

            // Pass the user sign-in credentials to the continuation
            authenticationContinuation.setAuthenticationDetails(authenticationDetails)

            // Allow the sign-in to continue
            authenticationContinuation.continueTask()
        }

        override fun getMFACode(multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation: MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation) {
            // Multi-factor authentication is required; get the verification code from user
            multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.setMfaCode(null)
            // Allow the sign-in process to continue
            multiFactorAuthenticationContinuation.continueTask()
        }

        override fun onFailure(exception: Exception) {
            // Sign-in failed, check exception for the cause
            Log.e(TAG, "${exception.message}")
        }
    }
    // Sign in the user
    user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler)
}
internal class SimpleAsyncTask(private val activity: Activity,private val credential:CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider) :
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void?):Void ?{
        credential.refresh()
        credential.setPersistenceEnabled(true)
        return null
    }
```

Similar kind of code is also used for facebook login like this

```
FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {




                        //Getting access Token

                        val accessToken = loginResult.accessToken.token

                        //Credentials Extraction
                        val credentials = CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(this@LoginActivity,resources.getString(R.string.cognito_identity_pool_id),Regions.myRegion)
                        credentials.clear()
                        //Map of login
                        val login = HashMap<String,String>()
                        login["graph.facebook.com"] = accessToken

                        //Setting the value of map
                        credentials.logins = login


                        //Off the main thread
                        SimpleAsyncTask(this@LoginActivity,credentials).execute()

                    }

                    override fun onCancel() {

                        //Cancel code
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,"Canceled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                        //Error code
                        Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity,exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                })
```

Now I am using this to check user status of login, I check the condition `cognitoCachingCredentialProvider.cachedId!=null` for checking user login. 
But it gets logged in for like an hour how to get user logged in for a long long time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh token is distinctly different from id or access token. You can use refresh token to get fresh access and id tokens (as the name suggests). When you call getSession it should automatically refresh your tokens if they have expired AND if your refresh token hasn't expired.

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39480690/6941447

Comment: Is there any example of this

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html
And
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoAuthDemo

Comment: Is there any better way than getSession because I have to call this thing every time even for the authenticated API calls. For example, one user resumes or opens the app and opens it after one hour of login and does something which requires an API call I have to call the first getSession and then I have to use the credentials?

Comment: You have to refresh your tokens every hour there is no getting around that. But there are libraries that automate a lot of this for you. I have personally never used this since I only work on back end, but I've heard a lot of good things about AWS amplify. Maybe you can try it out and see if it is more convenient for you. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/building-an-android-app-with-aws-amplify-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so as Ninad said we have to use `getSession` for refreshing credentials you have to just add this check.

```
     if(credentialsProvider.cachedIdentityId==null)
             {
userPool.currentUser.getSessionInBackground(AuthenticationHandler)
}
```

Make an authentication Handler seperate for this and your tokens are refreshed.